# How to play video in-game if you have the Window Device? (DirectX 9)

Tags: c++, windows, video, directx, directshow

I am using a game engine and I need to play a video cutscene in my game, so I can create a DLL extension to do this.

The engine provides the game's "Window Device" (DirectX 9) which I can pass to the DLL. Sadly it contains no examples of what I can do with it. So I have no idea how I am supposed to show the video.

I need to show the video file inside of the game's window. How could I use the Window Device to setup and display a surface of some kind with the video?

I am also using cutscene.cpp sample from the Windows SDK as a guide as I try to figure things out.

Any additional resources are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Older Microsoft DirectX 9.0 SDK offered Texture3D Sample ([still mentioned on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468) but discontninued as sample). It is the same source you took CutScene sample from.

> Microsoft DirectX 9.0  Texture3D Sample Description
>
> Draws video on a Microsoft® Direct3D texture surface.
>
> Note   This sample does not support changing the display properties of
>   the monitor while the sample is running.
>
> Path
>
> Source: (SDK root)\Samples\C++\DirectShow\Players\Texture3D
>   Executable: (SDK root)\Samples\C++\DirectShow\Bin\Texture3D.exe
>
> ---
>
> Desc: DirectShow sample code - adds support for DirectShow videos playing
>         on a DirectX 9.0 texture surface. Turns the D3D texture tutorial into
>         a recreation of the VideoTex sample from previous versions of DirectX.

Last time the sample was on DirectShow samples was DirectX SDK Extras February 2005 distribution.

Comment: You should be able to find those samples in the [Windows 7.1 SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/06/15/windows-sdk-7-1.aspx) (full version, not the 7.1A that is installed with VS 2012 Update 1+ or VS 2013 for "v110_xp" / "v120_xp" platform toolset support).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: Texture3D and a few other samples have been discontinued years ago and are taken away from SDK samples. It's a surprise MSDN article still mentions them in gray. One needs an old SDK to reach them. CutScene sample, on the other hand, is still there in place.

Comment: Right. CutScene is in SDK 7.1. Texture3D requires the SDK 6.1.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: Good find, Texture3D9 is indeed in 6.1. Texture3D needs a more ancient SDK (Texture3D9 is okay for the asker).